# in-line create for table new createable row

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've created the following simple MVC 5 application

> 1. create model (using code first) with 4 properties
> 2. I go to the controller and generate view  by scaffold.

this is working fine!
when I run the page and click on create button **I've navigated to new page** with the fields which I need to create (this is default behavior),
my question is if there is a way that when I click on create i will stay on the same page and **add to the table new empty line at the beginning** i.e. **inline create**  I have only one page
that the create just open new row in the table with text box and check boxes and having save button in the right side.

This is my simple model and the UI which generated by scaffold

```
namespace Emp01.Models
{
    public class Emp
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Boolean checkBox1 { get; set; }
        public Boolean checkBox2 { get; set; }
        public Boolean checkBox3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmpDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmpDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Emp> Emps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is the view**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox2)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox3)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**Update**

in addition like Patil suggest I try the following and I need you help

1. I add to the index page the code which was generated in the create operation and change the class form from vertical to inline.

2.add new div with ID of context that should toggle.

Currently I miss two things

1. how should I make the toogle works when I click on the button

2.when I run the page I got erorr in the link code(model=>model.name becouse its currenlty empty but also when you call to create page its empty so I dont understand why... )

I need you help please!

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
    });
    $("#addmoret").click(function () {
        $(".content").toggle();
    });
</script>

@* ----------------------------------------------------------- *@


          <div class="content">
              <div class="form-inline">
                  <h4>Role</h4>
                  <hr />
                  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                  <div class="form-group">

                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                      <div class="col-md-10">

                          @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@

                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.checkBox1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                              @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.checkBox1)*@
                              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.checkBox1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.checkBox2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                              @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.checkBox2)*@
                              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.checkBox2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.checkBox3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                              @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.checkBox3)*@
                              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.checkBox3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

**Update 2**

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

1: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable emp01.Models.emp>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

For the button I add

```
<button type='button' id='addmore' class="btn ui-state-default medium" value='Add More Credit ?' style="width: 200px;">Create </button>
```

Comment: $("#addmoret").click(function (){$(".content").toggle();}); in here "#addmoret" is the id of the button, so make sure its the id of your button. By the way are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: if you can see this is a Typo:  The id of your button is "addmore" and you are using "addmoret" this might be giving you error. Please correct it.

Comment: @KrunalPatil- thanks I already fix it but the model error is still exist can you please help

Comment: If you show me what are you passing to your page html page, Model or List ? something like this (@model SampleAsyncPartialViews.ViewModels.HomeViewModel)

Comment: @KrunalPatil  Can you please explain how to send it?

Comment: in that case i would suggest you to understand the MVC concept first. use this project and download the Music store project and learn how they pass model to views using controllers(This is one of the best applications to learn mvc)--> http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Comment: @KrunalPatil - I already learn it...what Can be the reason ,any idea? I can share the project in one drive if its ok or you having time...

Answer (score 3):

I was trying the same thing: 
The only thing is I'm using a division which opens when you click the button. As you can see the images.

You can achieve this by the code given below:

```
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".content").hide();
        });
        $("#addmorecredit").click(function () {
            $(".content").toggle();
        });
    </script>

<button type='button' id='addmorecredit' class="btn ui-state-default medium" value='Add More Credit ?' style="width: 200px;">Add More Credit ?</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="add-credit-form" class="content">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add More Credit</legend>
        <br />
        <div class="form-row form-input">
            <div class="form-label col-md-2">
                <label for="">Amount Paid (@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SelectedCurrency))<span class="required">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmountPaid)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AmountPaid)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row form-input">
            <div class="form-label col-md-2">
                <label for="">Creditor Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreditorName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CreditorName)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-label col-md-2">
                <label for="">Notes<span class="required">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Notes)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notes)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id='addcredit' class="btn ui-state-default medium">Add Credit</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<fieldset>
    <legend>Credit History</legend>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account Id</th>
                    <th>Creditor Name</th>
                    <th>Amount Credited</th>
                    <th>Banked?</th>
                    <th>Date Credited</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.PurchaseHistory)
                {                           
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(Convert.ToString(item.AccountId))</td>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(item.CreditorName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(Convert.ToString(item.Balance))</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(item.Datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"))</td>
                    </tr>
                        }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**The Images :**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Patil! voted up,There is a way that when you click on the table a new empty row will be added ,for example in you table when you click add you will see tree rows that the first is empty...I stuck with it almost 2 days.Thanks a lot

Comment: HI Patil can you please see my update I was tried to do someting similar for what you did and I got some error,can you help please?I can also share the project in one drive if its OK...Thanks in advance